Continue playing sound on remote computer when rdc disconnects
1I have an old computer with Windows 10 that I am using as an iTunes server. I use RDC to connect as there is no monitor connected. I play audio on the remote computer and everything works fine except when the client computer goes to sleep or disconnects. Then iTunes stops playing and goes into a state where I nearly have to close and reopen it to make it work. How can I have iTunes keep playing when RDC disconnects?

Use VNC.  It isn't better for most things, but it is indeed better for this.  It will keep the session open and you can enter and leave the logged in session as you please.
